# setup mysql with django

Tags: osx, mysql, django, virtualenv, mysql-connection

I am trying to setup mysql server with my django application but I am having trouble installing it correctly.

I used `brew install mysql` to install mysql server

Then I used `pip install mysqlclient` which gives this error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/r9/n0ld0jk57x590rzq5kv8x4wc0000gn/T/pip-build-XErPVD/mysqlclient/

Also tried, `pip install MySQL-python` but it also gives the same error message.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I recently shifted from Linux to mac OS and I am a little confused how things work here.

Note: I am trying to do this in a `virtual environment`.